# How to access the windows registry with javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, registry

I need to write to HKEY_CURRENTUSER using javascript. 
It should work on Google chrome 10 & 11 - WinXP and 7.
How do I do that?

Comment: I'm no JS dev, but I'm pretty sure this is impossible

Comment: Why do you need to write to local registry from a browser ?

Comment: I don't need to it from the browser, I need it for a chrome application

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't.  Allowing this via web browser would have pretty serious security consequences.

Comment: Click here to add this helpful keylogger to your startup

Comment: I thought so, wanted to make sure anyway.

Comment: Okay, so how do you do it in JavaScript that's NOT in a web browser? (i.e. launched at the command line with wscript)

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible due to security restrictions.  The browser should not be able to modify the local machine.

If you were doing this in IE, it would be possible using an Active X control, but in Chrome it is not possible at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can only do that on a windows machine you control, using c/wscript. [Example](http://ist.marshall.edu/ist334/wsh_registry.html)